# psycopg2 : Query Postgis Function

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I want to do Query : SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(-7.83753572095, 110.354612964)) ;

my python code =

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname = 'gis02', host= '127.0.0.1', user = 'gis2user',password= '123456')
cur = conn.cursor()

pointA={}
pointA['lat']=-7.83753572095
pointA['lon']=110.354612964

myquery = 'SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s)) ;'
pointA['geom']= cur.execute(myquery %(pointA['lat'], pointA['lon'])).fetchone()
```

The result is :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

when I do it directly in psql console I got :

```
POINT(-7.83753572095 110.354612964)
```

How to call Postgis's functions using psycopg2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fetchone()` is not a method of `cur.execute()` but of the cursor class (here: `cur`). So you cannot combine this in one line.

You need to first execute and then fetchone.

```
cur.execute(myquery %(pointA['lat'], pointA['lon']))
pointA['geom'] = cur.fetchone()
```

---

> [**execute(query, vars=None):**](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute)
>   The method returns **None**. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods.